# Unable to start mongodb without access control

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I am using EC2(for Ubuntu 16.04) and i have installed mongodb 3.6
but when i start it using following command

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
```

It is giving following error

```
An unsupported journal format detected - If you are trying to rollback from version 4.0 to 3.6, please re-start a 4.0 binary and cleanly shut it down so that the journal format will be downgraded.

Assertion: 28595:13: Permission denied src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 488

exception in initAndListen: Location28595: 13: Permission denied, terminating

Invariant failure globalStorageEngine src/mongo/db/service_context_d.cpp 272
```

please suggest

Comment: Perhaps look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/ and check upgrade/downgrade procedures

Comment: But what command, I am not finding proper command to replace binaries

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo service mongod restart
sudo service mongod status

sudo service mongod stop
sudo service mongod status
```

and then maybe your commands to follow